# Passing currently logged user to submit_line.html in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I have been trying to get the currently logged user object in submit_line.html to control which buttons it displays. However I have realized that the user object is not passed to the context for submit_row. What would be the best way to pass a the currently logged user object to submit_row. Should I create a new template tag?

Nicola

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current `User` by accessing the `request` object:

```
{{ request.user }}
```

Just make sure `'django.core.context_processors.request'` is included in `context_processors` setting in `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        ...
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            ...
            'django.core.context_processors.request', # this entry is important
        ],
    },
},]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can also use `{{ request.user }}` in your template to get login user. And also you can use template tag to get login user for that

first create .py file let's consider 'templatetags.py' and write this view there

```
@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def user_tag(context):
    request = context['request']
    return request.user
```

Now load this templatetags.py file in your html file i.e.'submit_line.html'

```
{% load templatetags %}

{% user_tag as user %}
{% if user %}
{{ user }}
{% endif %}
```

Hope this will help you.